# Import JSON file with javascript (not JQuery)

Tags: php, javascript, json

I've searched all over and haven't found a comprehensive tutorial or explanation on importing a JSON file (on the same server/directory) with just JavaScript and/or PHP.  I know using a library is better, but I want to know how to do it without.

Say I have the following in a `.json` file

```
{
   "customers":[
   {"name":"Joe Smith","age":"36"},
   {"name":"Jane Doe","age":"27"}
   ]
}
```

How would I effectively pull that into a script and use its data?

Comment: Are you server-side or client side? Essentially all you need to do is get the JSON itself, then parse it: [`JSON.parse(myJsonString)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Where is this `.json` file stored?

Comment: What do you mean by "local file", on the client side?

Comment: you need the `JSON` library to turn the json into javascript object(s), otherwise you would have to do an unsafe `eval()` for that

Comment: If this is a file local to the client machine, the answer is that you can't "include" a client-side local file.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying.  I actually meant local server side as in, on the same server and/or directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way without using Ajax is to echo the contents of the file from PHP into a javascript variable, like so. Because JSON uses the same structure as objects in Javascript, you can directly use the data as a variable.

```
var myData = <?php echo file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'); ?>;

// 2
console.log(myData.customers.length);
```

Note that this is assuming that the data is valid JSON. Also, make sure the source of the file is trusted because this can execute anything in the context of your document.

Comment: +1 but you should warn that this is valid only for **trusted** and correct json files

Comment: Yes, that should be assumed. I'll add it as a note in the answer.

Comment: I like this answer much better than the AJAX method. It avoids all the unpleasant complexities of various browsers, etc.

Comment: This is a great answer. Don't know why I didn't think of it before.  What is the major difference between just creating a regular old text file and a JSON file in that case?  Doesn't seem like that .json (opposed to .txt) is really necessary.

Comment: The only reason I can think of off the top of my head is the content disposition type assumed from the client if it were to be loaded in browser. For example, if you used jQuery it would return the data as an object by default. Ultimately it has no effect on how data is represented especially with this method.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to grab the data dynamically, you'd use a combination of `XMLHttpRequest` (to request the text) and `JSON.parse` (to parse it).

```
function getData(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            }
            else {
                callback(null); // Or something to indicate failure
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

// usage
getData("/path/to/your/file", function(data) {
    if (data === null) {
        // Handle the error
    }
    else {
        // Use `data` here
    }
});
```

Now, where libraries come in:

- Some older browsers don't support `new XMLHttpRequest` and require that you create the XHR object various different ways. A library helps you there by handling that for you.
- Some older (and not that old) browsers don't support `JSON.parse` natively yet, and so you may need a shim. You can find several on [Douglas Crockford's github page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/). But again, a decent library will handle that for you.